# Is there a way to track how many statements go to the Else clause and then assign a running value for each Else shown to run another prompt?

Tags: vbscript

```
'Option Explicit double checks my variables and spelling    
Option Explicit    

'Define variables needed throughout script in beginning   
Dim fso, BC1, strTestStr1,strTestStr1Length,BC2    
Dim strTestStr2,strTestStr2Length    
Dim TestComp    
Dim Total    
Set Total = Nothing 

'Set fso     
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
'Declare and Open BC1    
Set BC1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GDoe\Desktop\BC1.txt",1)    
strTestStr1 = BC1.ReadAll    
BC1.Close

'Declare and Open BC2    
Set BC2 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\GDoe\Desktop\BC2.txt",1)    
strTestStr2=BC2.ReadAll    
BC2.Close

'Determines if the A is within the String    
If(InStr(strTestStr1,"A")) Then    
    msgbox(strTestStr1)   
Else   
    msgbox("This is not an A Plate.")    
    Total = +1    
End If

'Determines if the E is within the String    
If (InStr(strTestStr2,"E")) Then    
    msgbox(strTestStr2)    
Else    
    msgbox("This is not an E Plate.")    
    Total = +1    
End If

'Cut the string "-####-######", File position 3, 12 characters long    
strTestStr1Length = mid(strTestStr1,3,12)    
strTestStr2Length = mid(strTestStr2,3,12)    

'Comparing my Strings    
TestComp = StrComp(strTestStr1Length,strTestStr2Length)    

 'If Comparison reveals mismatch with numbers, Message box displayed    
If TestComp <> 0 Then    
    msgbox("Mismatch")   
End If

If Total > 0 Then    
msgbox(Total)
```

Want to have a running count of times the conditions are false to activate
Another program at the end based on the Total. If Total>0 with the errors,
Follows one path if it is correct continues script.

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete, as it finishes in the middle of an If statement.

Comment: I forgot to add the final End If to the statement. I added it and made the changes you suggested and it works well now. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no shorthand/assignment+math operators in VBScript; so change

```
Total = +1  ' seen as assign +1 to Total
```

to

```
Total = Total + 1
```